# Ruby on Rails Tutorial 7.2.2 : rspec failure : action 'create' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The rspec test fails when trying to click_button "Create my account" saying "The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController.

I'm assuming that this is a RESTful problem where it's defaulting to POST instead of GET (or something like that).  Why oh why else would it be trying to call 'create' instead of 'new'?  In the next section - 7.3 - a 'create' action is defined but the tutorial says that tests should be passing by the end of 7.2.2.

On the other hand, I could simply be missing something.  That's why I'm not writing to admin at the tutorial site.

I'd post my code but I've verified that it's the same as the tutorial's examples:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up?version=3.2#sec:signup_form

Comment: I just looked over the HTML output for the form and it's definitely POSTing. Which means, RESTfully, that the action is 'create'.  So maybe it's just a mistake in the tutorial.  I'm going to bite the bullet and email Michael (admin).

Comment: Seeing from Listing 7.20, you can find that the generated HTML actually displays it is a POST action.  
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user"
      id="new_user" method="post">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything. It seems you are catching a slight doco error.

Indeed, Hartl says so right in the beginning of 7.3.1 "Our first step is to eliminate the error that currently results when submitting the signup form, as you can verify in your browser or *** by running the test for signup with invalid information ***" (my emphasis).

Still, I'd like him to clear this up as well, there seems to be just a little more to this. I also happen to be not catching any regex errors for poorly formed email addresses.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but I've just had this same problem and I'll post this in case anyone new needs help.

What confused me was the sentence in 7.2.2: "With the @user variable so defined, the test for the signup page should be passing again." But my tests were failing even though my code was exactly the same as the example.

The problem was, not all the tests *should* be passing - Hartl is only talking about the "signup page" tests. At this point some tests under "signup" should be failing.

If you run the command Hartl gives you should see that the right tests do pass:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "signup page"
```

I'd just been being lazy and only typing `bundle exec rspec spec/`, which ran the failing tests too.

Comment: Additionally there is an error in listing 7.16: the "signup" test is called "signup page", which caused me to add the tests to the existing signup page test as opposed to creating a new signup test. You can see it is corrected here: https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

Answer (score 3):

Part of the confusion for me was that when Michael described the new "signup" tests, I thought he had renamed/generalized the previously created "signup page" tests.  In retrospect, I should not have made that assumption and realized that he retained the "signup page" tests as separate from the "signup" tests.  My error was compounded by the fact that I'd taken his earlier suggestion and had been running guard/spork, so in general I was not executing the tests from the command line, thus missing the specific test reference he had included.